# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Additional information: Error converting data type varchar to bigint. in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-2.0

This Is My Codding i have face this type of error in my code

> (Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
> System.Data.dll

**Additional information:** Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Update Query:___________________________________

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    query = ("update items set name='" + txtName.Text + "',category='" + txtCategory.Text + "',price='" + txtPrice.Text + "where iid =" + id + "'");
    fn.setData(query);
    loadData();
    txtName.Clear();
    txtCategory.Clear();
    txtPrice.Clear();
}
```

---

Set Query_______________

```
public void setData(String query)
{
    SqlConnection con = getConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();


    MessageBox.Show("Data Processed Successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}
```

Comment: Yikes. This is scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues. You need to look up how to use parameterized queries. Also, as a nice bonus, **converting to a parameterized query will almost certainly also fix the problem in your question.**

Comment: dear sir if possible then please give example.

Comment: Use parameterized queries 
https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=parameterized sql query example

Comment: Think very carefully about what would happen if I entered "`';DROP TABLE Items;--`" as the name. (Hint: probably nothing, since the user likely does not have enough permissions... but more subtle attacks and invasive attacks are also possible and _not that difficult_.

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use **Parameterized Query** or **Stored Procedure**, rather than **injecting** values.

`btnUpdate_Click`

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    query = ("update items set name = @name, category = @category, price = @price where iid = @id");
    fn.setData(query,long.Parse(id),txtName.Text, txtCategory.Text, long.Parse(txtPrice.Text));
    loadData();
    txtName.Clear();
    txtCategory.Clear();
    txtPrice.Clear();
}
```

`setData function`

```
public void setData(String query, long id,string name, string category, long price)
{
    SqlConnection con = getConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", category);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
    {
        DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int64, //For big int
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
        ParameterName = "@id",
        Value = id
    });
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Processed Successfully.", "Success",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // catch exception here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Change your code as highlighted below, it should solve your problem.

```
{    
    query = ("update items set name='" + txtName.Text + "',category='" + txtCategory.Text + "',price= **" +int.Parse(txtPrice.Text) +** "where iid =" + id + "'");

    fn.setData(query);
    loadData();
    txtName.Clear();
    txtCategory.Clear();
    txtPrice.Clear();
}
```

Comment: This contains the  same bugs as the original. First, arbitrary text can be included in the text fields and end up altering the query, including, eg `'; DROP TABEL USERS;--`. Second, if `txtPrice.Text` contains a non-numeric value, this code will through again. It will be a different error, still saying that the text can't be converted

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).